# Preventing workstation from getting to specific IP

Tags: windows-7, vmware-view

I'm working in a VMware View 5 environment and I'm looking for a way to prevent fat clients from getting to particular View Connection brokers. I've been thinking of either using a static route or possibly a Windows firewall rule, but was curious to hear if anyone else might have some suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Put your fat clients on a separate VLAN/Subnet and use an ACL on the L3 device/firewall to prevent them from getting to whatever IP they shouldn't be able to get to.

Comment: thats a great idea, the problem is, there isn't enough separation of these devices currently to assume that an entire subnet range can be excluded.  Using a separate subnet although ideal, isn't a good option for this client currently